# How to fix ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error in Next JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, compiler-errors

Whenever I try to run my Node JS project (`npm run dev`) or build it (`npm run build`), I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in C:\React Tutorials\react-complete-guide-18\node_modules\postcss\package.json
```

How can I fix this so that I can run/build the package?

Answer (score 0):

run `npm update` and than `npm audit fix --force`

The update command will update all the versions for the installed modules.

Comment: That didn't work. I tried running just the `npm update` command, but I still got the same error. After running `npm audit fix --force`, it upgraded my react version, then the s**t hit the fan. I decided to delete my node_modules folder and reinstall the project dependencies from the start, but now it can't even do that because of some dependency conflicts.